# issue libusb_set_auto_detach_kernel_drive not found with pylibftdi with python software Psychopy

Tags: libusb, psychopy, ftdi, libftdi

I have been able to add the pylibftdi to Pyschopy (a python based software made to build an run psychology experiment).
My FTDI device is detected but I have the error below.
I had previouly this error in Anaconda and solved it by creating a new environnement because it was also imposible to have it working in the base environnment.
Unfortunately, I don't think a can create a new environnment in Psychopy and I am stuck with this error that prevents me to use both the pylibftdi and the psychopy GUI. I was not able to find any relevant file online, but try to install the newest version of psychopy.

````
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy\lib\site-packages\pylibftdi\bitbang.py", line 62, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy\lib\site-packages\pylibftdi\bitbang.py", line 68, in open
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy\lib\site-packages\pylibftdi\device.py", line 254, in open
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 386, in __getattr__
    # XXX Hm, what about HRESULT as normal parameter?
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 391, in __getitem__
    # _check_retval_ is called with the function's result when it
AttributeError: function 'libusb_set_auto_detach_kernel_driver' not found```
````